# Black Screen after 12.04 Installation

Tags: installation, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) on a new Windows 8 Sony laptop that I have bought recently.

When I attempt to boot Ubuntu all that appears is a black screen with a single coloured line across the top. Could this be the result of some incompatibility with the system graphics card, AMD Radeon HD 7650M 1GB?

How do I solve this?

Thanks you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot your system using nomodeset parameter. You can set this parameter when grub loads press E button. Look for the line that starts as

```
linux /boot
```

and add in the end of the line word nomodeset. So it should look like this

```
linux /boot ********* quite splash nomodeset
```

After that press CRTL+ x and see if you can boot now. If it successful I recommend you try to install FGRLX frivers for your card. You can find HOW-TO here

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)